# Show that if $M = M_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus M_n$ then $T(M) = T(M_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus T(M_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules

*Definitions:*

- $M_i$ are $R$ modules;
- $\text{ann}(x) = \{r \in R \mid rx = 0\}$;
- $T(M)=\{m \in M \mid \text{ann}(m) \neq \{0\}\}$;

*Problem*

Show that if $M = M_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus M_n$ then $T(M) = T(M_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus T(M_n)$.

*My Solution:*

Let $x \in T(M) \subseteq M$. It follows that $x = m_1 + \cdots + m_n$ where $m_i \in M_i$. Since $\text{ann}(x) \neq \{0\}$, there is a $r \in R\setminus\{0\}$ such that $rx = 0$, hence:
$$
0 = rx = r(m_1 + \cdots + m_n) = rm_1 + \cdots + rm_n \implies rm_i=0
$$
Therefore if $x \in T(M)$ then $r \in \text{ann}(m_i)$ for $i \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ which follows that each $m_i$ is a torsion element of $M_i$. Therefore:
$$
T(M) = T(M_1) + \cdots + T(M_n)
$$
Now to show that this sum is direct, consider two different decompositions of an element $y \in T(M)$:
$$
t_1' + \cdots + t_n' = y = t_1 + \cdots + t_n \implies t_1'-t_1 + \cdots + t_n' - t_n = 0
$$
Since $0 = t_1'-t_1 + \cdots + t_n' - t_n  \in M_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus M_n = M$ we have that:
$$
(t_1'-t_1) + \cdots + (t_n' - t_n) = 0 + \cdots + 0 \implies t_i' - t_i = 0 \implies t_i' = t_i
$$
Which shows that the sum is direct.

---

That is a problem from the Modules chapter of the book Introduction to Abstract Algebra - W.Keith Nicholson.

Can someone please check my solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not true if $R$ is not a domain. For example, take

$$
\mathbb{Z}_6 = \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3
$$

as a $\mathbb{Z}_6$-module. Then $t(\mathbb{Z}_6) = 0$ but $t(\mathbb{Z}_2),t(\mathbb{Z}_3) \neq 0$.

When $R$ is a domain, the other inclusion you have ommitted is proven as follows: if $m_i \in M_i$ are torsion elements, so that $r_i m_i = 0$ for $r_i \neq 0$, then defining $r := r_1 \cdots r_n$ (which is nonzero precisely because $R$ is a domain) we have

$$
r\sum_im_i = \sum_irm_i = \sum_i (r_1 \cdots \widehat{m_i} \cdots r_n)r_im_i = 0,
$$

and thus $m_1 + \cdots +m_n \in t(M)$.

Some other remarks:

- you can also prove this for two modules, and proceed by induction.
- at the end, you already know that $t(M_i) \subset M_i$ and it is a general fact that if $M = M_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus M_n$ and $S_i \leq M_i$ are submodules, then their sum is direct (and the proof is the one you have written).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to say that R is a domain.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed the exercise had that hypothesis, my point was more about the fact that you should also write the other inclusion (which is non trivial in the sense that it uses that R is a domain, and it is false otherwise).